# ListBox in Unity: how to do ?

Tags: unity, gui

I'm come from WinForm/.NET development, where there is a lot of 'cool' ready made widget like: combo box, list view with scrolling system included.

Now I'm using Unity and I'm trying to implement user GUI, but i'm facing some trouble because as i can see there aren't much ready made widget.

Specifically, I'm trying to implement a saving/loading system and i'm trying to add a window with a list box containing list of saving file.

What's the best widget / approach to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a [Dropdown menu](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Dropdown.html)?

Comment: No: listbox... Like a dropdown but always opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you can get this behaviour like so:

1. Create a new UI->ScrollView

   - Deactivate its horizontal scrolling checkbox
2. Navigate inside the ScrollView's hierarchy to Viewport -> Content
3. Add 2 components:

   - **Vertical Layout Group** (stacks contents vertically)
   - **Content Size Fitter** - set vertical fit to preferred size (expands container to the size of the list vertically, so it provokes a scroll bar)
4. Add your content items underneath this parent. They'll automatically stack & scroll when needed.

Comment: They've got a https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.ListView.html now.